# Yii2 and Google maps API

Tags: javascript, php, css, google-maps, yii2

I have an empty Yii2 project. I need set up Google Map to specified page. I know that I have to include my .js and .css files but I don't know how exactly. I tried to set up my scripts here in assets/AppAsset.php:

```
    public $css = [
    'css/site.css',
    'css/mystyles.css'
];
public $js = [
    'js/map-options.js',
    'js/data.json',
    'js/markerclusterer.js'
];
```

and add these lines in view-file and controller

```
// in view
$this->registerJsFile('path/to/myfile');
$this->registerCssFile('path/to/myfile');

// in controller
$this->view->registerJsFile('path/to/myfile');
$this->view->registerCssFile('path/to/myfile');
```

But it's still doesn't work. Help, how can I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

maybe your problem in your css.
try this:

```
#map{  
  position: absolute;}
```

or insert it inline